# Modal in Elm without framework

Tags: elm, elm-ui

I am new to ELM and I want to create a modal without the use of any libraries such as Bootstrap or ELM-UI. I found this simple example online which is also using JSON Decode. Is there a possibility to have the modal work simply without any framework/library and JSON Decode? How can I modify the code to simply get a working modal?

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, Attribute, button, div, span, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick, on)
import Html.Attributes exposing (class, style)
import Json.Decode as Decode


type alias Model =
    { isVisible : Bool, count : Int }


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { isVisible = False, count = 0 }


type Msg
    = Show
    | Hide
    | Increment
    | Decrement


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Show ->
            { model | isVisible = True }

        Hide ->
            { model | isVisible = False }
            
        Increment ->
            { model | count = model.count + 1 }
            
        Decrement ->
            { model | count = model.count - 1 }


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ button [ onClick Show ] [ text "Show!" ]
        , if model.isVisible then
            div
                ([ class dialogContainerClass
                 , on "click" (containerClickDecoder Hide)
                 ]
                    ++ dialogContainerStyle
                )
                [ div dialogContentStyle
                    [ span [] [ text "Click anywhere outside this dialog to close it!" ]
                    , span [] [ text "Clicking on anything inside of this dialog works as normal." ]
                    , div []
                        [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
                        , text (String.fromInt model.count)
                        , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
          else
            div [] []
        ]


dialogContainerClass : String
dialogContainerClass = "dialog-container-class"


containerClickDecoder : msg -> Decode.Decoder msg
containerClickDecoder closeMsg =
    Decode.at [ "target", "className" ] Decode.string
        |> Decode.andThen
            (\c ->
                if String.contains dialogContainerClass c then
                    Decode.succeed closeMsg

                else
                    Decode.fail "ignoring"
            )



dialogContainerStyle : List (Attribute msg)
dialogContainerStyle =
    [ style "position" "absolute"
    , style "top" "0"
    , style "bottom" "0"
    , style "right" "0"
    , style "left" "0"
    , style "display" "flex"
    , style "align-items" "center"
    , style "justify-content" "center"
    , style "background-color" "rgba(33, 43, 54, 0.4)"
    ]
    
    
dialogContentStyle : List (Attribute msg)
dialogContentStyle =
    [ style "border-style" "solid"
    , style "border-radius" "3px"
    , style "border-color" "white"
    , style "background-color" "white"
    , style "height" "120px"
    , style "width" "440px"
    , style "display" "flex"
    , style "flex-direction" "column"
    , style "align-items" "center"
    , style "justify-content" "center"
    ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem you're trying to solve is clicking outside the modal to close it. Decoding the event object to get information about the DOM is a bit of a hack in Elm – I think you're right to try to avoid it, unless necessary. One way to achieve the same thing is to add a click event handler with [stop propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to your modal contents – this stops the click event from firing on the container when it originates from within the modal.

I've put your example code in an Ellie and made some small changes: https://ellie-app.com/b9gDPHgtz2ca1

This solution uses [Html.Events.stopPropagationOn](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#stopPropagationOn), which is like `on` but does a call to `event.stopPropagation()`. This function *does* require you to supply a decoder, so I'm afraid you can't get away from importing `Json.Decode`, but we are using the simplest possible decoder – `Decode.succeed` – and only to satisfy the parameters of the function.

I've added a `NoOp` variant to `Msg`, as there is nothing to do when the modal is clicked; simply attaching this event handler stops the `Hide` event from firing when we don't want it to.

#### Code

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Attribute, Html, button, div, span, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (class, style)
import Html.Events exposing (on, onClick)
import Json.Decode as Decode


type alias Model =
    { isVisible : Bool, count : Int }


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { isVisible = False, count = 0 }


type Msg
    = Show
    | Hide
    | Increment
    | Decrement
    | NoOp


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Show ->
            { model | isVisible = True }

        Hide ->
            { model | isVisible = False }

        Increment ->
            { model | count = model.count + 1 }

        Decrement ->
            { model | count = model.count - 1 }

        NoOp ->
            model


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ button [ onClick Show ] [ text "Show!" ]
        , if model.isVisible then
            div
                (onClick Hide
                    :: dialogContainerStyle
                )
                [ div
                    (onClickStopPropagation NoOp
                        :: dialogContentStyle
                    )
                    [ span [] [ text "Click anywhere outside this dialog to close it!" ]
                    , span [] [ text "Clicking on anything inside of this dialog works as normal." ]
                    , div []
                        [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
                        , text (String.fromInt model.count)
                        , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]

          else
            div [] []
        ]


onClickStopPropagation : msg -> Html.Attribute msg
onClickStopPropagation msg =
    Html.Events.stopPropagationOn "click" <| Decode.succeed ( msg, True )


dialogContainerStyle : List (Attribute msg)
dialogContainerStyle =
    [ style "position" "absolute"
    , style "top" "0"
    , style "bottom" "0"
    , style "right" "0"
    , style "left" "0"
    , style "display" "flex"
    , style "align-items" "center"
    , style "justify-content" "center"
    , style "background-color" "rgba(33, 43, 54, 0.4)"
    ]


dialogContentStyle : List (Attribute msg)
dialogContentStyle =
    [ style "border-style" "solid"
    , style "border-radius" "3px"
    , style "border-color" "white"
    , style "background-color" "white"
    , style "height" "120px"
    , style "width" "440px"
    , style "display" "flex"
    , style "flex-direction" "column"
    , style "align-items" "center"
    , style "justify-content" "center"
    ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Comment: How do I create a close button within the modal that would help me in getting out of the modal? Would that be the solution to not using JSON decode? Could you please if possible update the code with a close button inside the modal which would close it? @Igid

Comment: From your code it looks like you know how to create a button that emits a msg on click. So rather than having onClick on each div, just have it on an "x" button. That would certainly eradicate the need for importing Json.Decode. But can I ask why you are at pains to avoid this module/package? If you have an Elm application of any reasonable size, you will eventually need to use it some way or another.

Comment: PS. I edited my answer to make clear that decoding the `event` object isn't hacky in itself, it's using that to get information/access to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am trying to avoid JSON.Decode because I just normally want a close button that would exit me from the modal. I checked the code provided by you but it still didn't answer my question. Within the modal, where there is an increment button/decrement button, below that I want to create a "close button" which would help me to close the modal rather than clicking outside Could you please guide me on how to do that? An example would be https://prnt.sc/utg839